# Photo eye sensor signal wiring

Tags: photosensor

I am trying to install a photo eye to use for a lay down bottle sensor.

I wired in the power, it turns on the light on the sensor flags when triggered.

But I’m not abel to trace where the signal is happening on the wiring. It’s a 4 pin and below is the schematic . Someone told me they had to use a relay to get it working something about separate power. But the photo eye should be self contained. So I don’t know why they needed to add extra stuff to get it to work.

Below is the schematic it comes with. Any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated. I can get it to work with the relay. Like the other person suggested I’m just not sure why.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: the output is `load`, pin 2  ... it tells you right by your finger

Comment: If i connect pin 2 the black wire to the plc I do not get a signal. Which is why I am here. This is not so black and white. Its 24v system.

Comment: why is that information missing from the question?

Comment: seems pretty straight forward ... the output is Open Collector ... wire it same as a mechanical switch

Comment: I was able to figure it out and updated my question

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. It did not work because the signal wire outputs 3vdc and the plc input is 24 source. So I had to set it to pnp and use black as my signal wire. Because this way the kid completed the circuit. I could not use white wire on npn because it was on the low side of the circuit

Comment: Tip: when posting a question please post the link to the datasheet so we can get context and missing details.